# Adding multiple queues in hosted service

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, queue, backgroundworker

I am implementing queues using https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio example.

this is how my code looks:

in startup.cs I am adding my hosted service and background queue

`services.AddHostedService<QueuedHostedService>();
services.AddSingleton<IBackgroundTaskQueue, BackgroundTaskQueue>();`

then I implement scoped service, hosted service and background queue as following:

```js
namespace Services.Services {
  public class QueuedHostedService: BackgroundService {
    private readonly ILogger _logger;
    private readonly IServiceProvider _serviceProvider;
    public QueuedHostedService(IServiceProvider serviceProvider, IBackgroundTaskQueue taskQueue, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory) {
      _serviceProvider = serviceProvider;
      TaskQueue = taskQueue;
      _logger = loggerFactory.CreateLogger < QueuedHostedService > ();
    }
    public IBackgroundTaskQueue TaskQueue {
      get;
    }

    protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken) {
      while (!cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested) {
        var workItem = await TaskQueue.DequeueAsync(cancellationToken);

        try {
          await workItem(cancellationToken);
        } catch (Exception ex) {

        }
      }
    }
  }
}


public interface IBackgroundTaskQueue {
  void QueueBackgroundWorkItem(Func < CancellationToken, Task > workItem);
  Task < Func < CancellationToken, Task >> DequeueAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken);
}

namespace Services.Services {
  public class BackgroundTaskQueue: IBackgroundTaskQueue {
    private ConcurrentQueue < Func < CancellationToken, Task >> _workItems = new ConcurrentQueue < Func < CancellationToken, Task >> ();
    private SemaphoreSlim _signal = new SemaphoreSlim(0);
    public void QueueBackgroundWorkItem(Func < CancellationToken, Task > workItem) {
      if (workItem == null) {
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(workItem));
      }
      _workItems.Enqueue(workItem);
      _signal.Release();
    }

    public async Task < Func < CancellationToken, Task >> DequeueAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken) {
      await _signal.WaitAsync(cancellationToken);
      _workItems.TryDequeue(out
        var workItem);
      return workItem;
    }
  }
}


// scoped service
namespace Services.Services {
  public class ImportService: BaseService, IImportService {
    private readonly IFileProcessingService _scopedProcessingService;

    private readonly ConfigurationSettings _configurationSettings;
    public IBackgroundTaskQueue Queue {
      get;
    }
    private
    const string AZURE_BLOB_CONTAINER = "blobcontainer";

    public IServiceProvider Services {
      get;
    }

    public ImportService(IServiceProvider services, IBackgroundTaskQueue queue): base(services) {
      Services = services;
      _configurationSettings = services.GetService < ConfigurationSettings > ();
      _scopedProcessingService = services.GetProcessingService();
      Queue = queue;
    }

    // ---- Main file
    public async Task ImportFile(string filePath, long fileSize, int userId, FileFormatType fileFormat, TransactionsDataHeadersMap dataHeadersMap, string delimiter, string dateFormat) {
      await _scopedProcessingService.ImportFile(filePath, fileSize, userId, fileFormat, dataHeadersMap, delimiter, dateFormat);
    }

    public async Task UploadToBlobStorage(IFormFile file, int userId, TransactionalDataFileType type) {
      var fileFormat = GetFileFormat(file);
      var tempFilePath = await GetTemporaryPath(file);
      var fileName = userId.ToString() + "-" + DateTime.Now + "." + fileFormat;
      // ....... //

      ProcessFile(tempFilePath, fileFormat, file, type, userId);
    }

    private void ProcessFile(string tempFilePath, FileFormatType fileFormat, IFormFile file, Tyoe type, int userId) {
      var delimiter = ",";
      Queue.QueueBackgroundWorkItem(async token => {
        using(var scope = Services.CreateScope()) {
          var scopedProcessingService =
            scope.ServiceProvider
            .GetRequiredService < IFileProcessingService > ();

          // do the processing
          switch (type) {
            case "csv":
              await scopedProcessingService.ImportFile(tempFilePath, file.Length, userId, fileFormat, new Headers(), delimiter ? ? ",", "yyyy-MM-dd");
              break;
          }
        }
      });
    }
  }
}
```

I am adding elemeents to queue on request in controller. Now I want to add another queue for pocessing other requests. Is it possible to use another queue using same Hosted service? I have trouble finding examples how to do that. Should I just add another scoped servide and another background queue?

Comment: Yes, adding another pair of services is one of ways how you can achieve this.

Comment: Is this the best way? What are other ways?

Comment: It depends on situation. Another is handling introducing concept of message types and handling different messages in one queue.

Comment: So I can have one `QueuedHostedService` and just add different tasks with `Queue.QueueBackgroundWorkItem(async token .....` like in `ProcessFile()` method? Or better practice would be to have e.g. `FileProcessingHostedService` and another `CalculationsHostedService`? something like here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/microservices/multi-container-microservice-net-applications/background-tasks-with-ihostedservice? but then do I need `BackgroundTaskQueue` for each? Maybe you know some other example resources that I could look up to? thank you in advance

Comment: Yes, that's the idea. You can try to reuse BackgroundTaskQueue adding generics. If you want, I can elaborate on that later.

Comment: I would really appreciate if you could!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. The first option  is the most straightforward - you just create bunch of classes and interfaces `QueuedHostedServiceA`, `QueuedHostedServiceB`, `IBackgroundTaskQueueA`.. (you can use inheritance to reduce code duplication)
2. Also you can introduce concept of "handler" and make all this stuff generic:

```
interface IHandler<T> { Task Handle(T msg, CancelationToken ...)}
interface IBackgroundMessageQueue<T> {...} // same impl but with T instead of Func<CancellationToken,Task>
class IBackgroundMessageQueue<T> {...} // same impl but with T instead of Func<CancellationToken,Task>

class QueuedHostedService<T>
{
   public QueuedHostedService(..., IBackgroundMessageQueue<T> queue, IHandler<T> h) {... }
   protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken) {
      while (!cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested) {
        T message = await queue.DequeueAsync(cancellationToken);

        try {
            using(var scp = serviceProvider.CreateScope())
            {
                var handler = ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<IHandler<T>>;
              await handler.Handle(message, cancellationToken);
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {

        }
      }
    }
}
```

And for each message type you create your own handler:

```
class ProcessFile(string tempFilePath, FileFormatType fileFormat, IFormFile file, Tyoe type, int userId){}

FileProcessor: IHandler<ProcessFile> {implement your logic from ImportService.ProcessFile}
```

Then you register everything:

```
services.AddScoped<IHandler<ProcessFile>, FileProcessor>()
services.AddSingleton<IBackgroundTaskQueue<ProcessFile>, BackgroundTaskQueue<ProcessFile>>();

services.AddHostedService<QueuedHostedService<ProcessFile>>();
```

and in your `ImportService` you resolve typed queue:

```
public ImportService(IBackgroundMessageQueue<ProcessFile> queue)
```

and enqueue message in it when needed.

Comment: thank you so much for your answer! just one more question. What is `class ProcessFile(string tempFilePath, FileFormatType fileFormat, IFormFile file, Type type, int userId){}`? it should only contain the constructor with the parameters needed for my processing? Sorry for asking so much I'm really trying to understand that. Also I can I call different services/repositories inside my `FileProcessor: IHandler<ProcessFile> {implement your logic from ImportService.ProcessFile}` since everything was inside scope in tis method before?