# How can I register multiple HostedServices using a single class with different arguments in the constructor?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, .net-7.0

I am working on a .NET Core hosted service and have encountered a problem that I'm unable to resolve. I'm trying to **register three instances of the "MyBackgroundService" class** as hosted services, each with a different integer parameter "i" ranging from 1 to 3. I'm instantiating these services through the scope, as shown in the code snippet below. **However, breakpoint in the "MyBackgroundService" class, it's only hit once.**

My question is: how can I register these services in a way that would allow me to run them as three separate services? The actual work is done in the "_myService.TemplateFiles" method. I would appreciate any help or advice.

```
var builder = Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args);

string env = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT") ?? "Production";
string version = typeof(Program).Assembly.GetName().Version.ToString();
var config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
    .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env}.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true).Build();

var v = config.GetConnectionString("yshDb");

String logpath = Path.Join(Path.GetDirectoryName(Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainModule.FileName), "TestServices.csv");

var csvLoggerProvider = new CsvLoggerProvider<MyBackgroundService>(logpath);

IHostBuilder hostBuilder = Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args);

hostBuilder.ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) =>
    {
        services.AddSingleton<ILoggerProvider>(csvLoggerProvider);
        services.AddDbContext<MyDBContext>(options =>
            options.UseSqlServer(hostContext.Configuration.GetConnectionString("connStr")), ServiceLifetime.Scoped);
        services.BuildServiceProvider();

        services.AddScoped<IDocumentMoveData, DocumentMoveData>();
        for (int i = 1; i <= 3; ++i)
        {
            services.AddHostedService<MyBackgroundService>(s =>
            {
                var scope = s.CreateScope();
                IServiceProvider scprov = scope.ServiceProvider;

                return new MyBackgroundService(scprov.GetService<IDocumentMoveData>(),
                    scprov.GetService<MyDBContext>(), i,
                    scprov.GetService<ILogger<MyBackgroundService>>());
            });
        }
    });

IHost host = hostBuilder.Build();

await host.StartAsync();
String s = Console.ReadLine();


public class MyBackgroundService : BackgroundService
    {
        private readonly ILogger<MyBackgroundService> _logger;
        private readonly IDocumentMoveData _myService;
        private readonly MyDBContext _dbContext;
        private readonly int _instanceNumber;

        public MyBackgroundService(IDocumentMoveData myService, MyDBContext dbContext, int instanceNumber, ILogger<MyBackgroundService> logger)
        {
            _myService = myService;
            _dbContext = dbContext;
            _instanceNumber = instanceNumber;
            _logger = logger;
        }

        protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
        {
            while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
                List<DocumentInfo> files = _myService.TemplateFiles(instanceNumber);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In short it is not possible via `AddHostedServices` - internally it calls `TryAddEnumerable` ([source](https://source.dot.net/#Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Abstractions/ServiceCollectionHostedServiceExtensions.cs,25)) which performs check if such service was added ([source](https://source.dot.net/#Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions/Extensions/ServiceCollectionDescriptorExtensions.cs,474)):

```cs
if (service.ServiceType == descriptor.ServiceType &&
    service.GetImplementationType() == implementationType)
{
    // Already added
    return;
}
```

You can try hacky solution by just registering it manually (at your personal risk =):

```cs
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{
    var tmp = i;
    services.AddTransient<IHostedService>(sp => new Worker(tmp, sp.GetRequiredService<ILogger<Worker>>()));
}
```

But I would recommend change approach and either create different types (`Worker1`, `Worker2`, ...) or better change worker to handle multiple parameters - for example using multiple threads (something similar to what is done in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61887338/2501279)).